# Objects are not valid as a React child, recived data in console but not on display

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I received dataAddress in the console with actual coordinates x, y. But I have a problem Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). I really don't understand what is wrong.

```
const BlogPage = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query{
    allContentfulBlogPost{
      edges{
        node{
          location{lat, lon}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  const token = 'token';
  let getAddress = async (x, y) => {
    const api_url = await fetch(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${x},${y}.json?access_token=${token}`)
    const dataAddress = await api_url.json()
    console.log(dataAddress);
  }
  return (
    <Layout>

      {
        data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((edge) => {
          return (
            <p>
              {
                getAddress(edge.node.location.lat, edge.node.location.lon)
              }
            </p>

          )
        })
      }
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Comment: When you call your function it returns an object...

Answer (score 3):

A number of things are wrong in your code. Firstly, you should put the API call in a useEffect hook so it doesn't get called upon every render. Secondly, the function `getAddress()` returns a Promise object as it is marked as `async`. So you can't pass that in as a React child without at least adding the `await` keyword.  Also you should have `getAddress()` function return the data of interest (probably the value of `dataAddress`) so you can use that value outside the function (right now, the function doesn't return anything). Or even better, set that value to your React state.

You could try:

```js
...
const [address, setAddress] = React.useState({});

React.useEffect(() => {
  getAddress(edge.node.location.lat, edge.node.location.lon);
}, [])
...
```

And in the `getAddress()` function, set your returned value as part of your state:

```js
let getAddress = async (x, y) => {
    const api_url = await fetch(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${x},${y}.json?access_token=${token}`)
    const dataAddress = await api_url.json()
    console.log(dataAddress);
    setAddress(dataAddress);
}
```

And in your JSX, just use the state value

```
...
<Layout>
    {data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((edge) => {
        return (
            <p>{address}</p>
        )
    })}
</Layout>
...
```

Of course, this assumes the value of `address` isn't an object. If it is you'd have to use only primitive properties of that object in your JSX. For example, if it's an object with properties: x and y, your JSX could look like

```
...
<p>({address.x}, {address.y})</p>
...
```